# UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft not show UIView second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, uiviewanimation

I am trying to Flip two `UIViews`. I've try to flip `UIView` using programmatically and it works perfect. But when i've try to flip `UIView` that i created in `storyboard` it not works, First time it flip UIView but second time it flip blank `UiViews`? Any one have any idea is there any mistake in my code?

[image]
In this picture Top left `Debug view Hierarchy` picture is before animating button and bottom left `Debug view Hierarchy` picture is after animating picture.

When second time i animate the `UIView` it Flip like this below picture.
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var blueSquare : UIView!
    @IBOutlet var redSquare : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func animateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        // create a 'tuple' (a pair or more of objects assigned to a single variable)
        var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

        if ((self.redSquare.superview) != nil) {
            views = (frontView: self.redSquare, backView: self.blueSquare)
        }
        else {
            views = (frontView: self.blueSquare, backView: self.redSquare)
        }

        // set a transition style
        let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft

        // with no animation block, and a completion block set to 'nil' this makes a single line of code
        UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView, toView: views.backView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

> **Programmatically**
>   That code is perfectly works.

```
let container = UIView()
let redSquare = UIView()
let blueSquare = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set container frame and add to the screen
    self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 200, height: 200)
    self.view.addSubview(container)

    // set red square frame up
    // we want the blue square to have the same position as redSquare 
    // so lets just reuse blueSquare.frame
    self.redSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    self.blueSquare.frame = redSquare.frame

    // set background colors
    self.redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.blueSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    // for now just add the redSquare
    // we'll add blueSquare as part of the transition animation 
    self.container.addSubview(self.redSquare)   
}

@IBAction func animateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // create a 'tuple' (a pair or more of objects assigned to a single variable)
    var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

    if((self.redSquare.superview) != nil){
        views = (frontView: self.redSquare, backView: self.blueSquare)
    }
    else {
        views = (frontView: self.blueSquare, backView: self.redSquare)
    }

    // set a transition style
    let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft

    // with no animation block, and a completion block set to 'nil' this makes a single line of code  
    UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView, toView: views.backView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)

}
```

> **UPDATE**

```
var check = true
 @IBAction func animateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // create a 'tuple' (a pair or more of objects assigned to a single variable)
    var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

    if (check == true) {

        views = (frontView: self.redSquare, backView: self.blueSquare)
        check = false
    }
    else {
        views = (frontView: self.blueSquare, backView: self.redSquare)
        check = true
    }

    // set a transition style
    let transitionOptions : UIViewAnimationOptions = [UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, UIViewAnimationOptions.ShowHideTransitionViews]
    // with no animation block, and a completion block set to 'nil' this makes a single line of code
    UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView, toView: views.backView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour for `transitionFromView` removes the view after animation.

```
let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.TransitionFlipFromLeft, .ShowHideTransitionViews]
```

From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@UIViewAnimationOptions

> - ShowHideTransitionViews
>
> When present, this key causes views to be hidden or shown (instead of removed or added) when performing a view transition. Both views must already be present in the parent view’s hierarchy when using this key. If this key is not present, the to-view in a transition is added to, and the from-view is removed from, the parent view’s list of subviews.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene H, i add this, but now it shows me that error `Cannot convert value of type '[UIViewAnimationOptions]' to expected argument type 'UIViewAnimationOptions'` on last line. Can you please fix it ?

Comment: Oh, must be an issue with your type declaration. See edit above with my declaration

Comment: To be clear, UIViewAnimationOptions is an OptionSetType. For more info, see http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2015/6/17/exploring-swift-20-optionsettypes

Comment: can you please check it in my project stil there is an issue, first time it animate and but next time it not show red view, just showing blue view :(  `drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxOHhnN3BIeE42T00`

Comment: Seems like the issue is with  if((self.redSquare.superview) != nil){ . Remember either views are not longer removed, so you should check for hidden state instead. I shouldn't be debugging your code for you. Please post a full question if you are still stuck

Comment: I've check my code, the problem is that every time if condition is execute not else. And after first time animating it removes `redSquare` from Debug view Hierarchy. I add bool `check`, using this check animation now works perfectly because now conditions are execute by sequence i mean not execute only if condition every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120896/discussion-between-zafar007-and-eugene-h).

Answer (score 0):

Ah in storyboard I see that you add both views to the container but in code you only add the redsquare. Perhaps remove the bluesquare from being within the container in storyboard?

Comment: I have tried this but still same problem, can you please try to fix it in my code.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxOHhnN3BIeE42T00  Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work like this, you ask questions and we try to help you solve your issues. But simply assuming that I will fix your code is going way too far..

Comment: I thought may be you batter understand where is exact problem if you see directly in my code. Ok no problem i'll trying to resolve it. Thanks